# Map multiple people in multiple States

Tags: excel, powerview

I am looking for a way to chart out some Excel data onto a PowerView map. I'd like to see which person within my group is most active in each state. However, when I'm running with the data in Excel and PowerView, it lists every person and their activity in each state. I just want to show each state with the most active user.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do you have any example data?  You need to use `MODE` & `MATCH` for this in an array, so `MODE(MATCH(A1:A5,A1:A5))` will give the row number of the most occuring, so `A,B,A,B,A,E` will give 4, the last A, so `INDEX` the column will give the value, so `INDEX(A1:A5,MODE(MATCH(A1:A5,A1:A5)),1)` would return A.

Without seeing your data, i cant really answer fully, you'll probably need to add another array to select the state.